# $\sum_{m=1}^n 1/m \sim log(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, expectation

Let $Y_1,Y_2,...$ be independent with $$P(Y_m=1)=\frac{1}{m}$$ and $$P(Y_m=0)=1-\frac{1}{m}$$
        $$E[Y_m]=\frac{1}{m} $$ and $$ Var[Y_m]=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m^2}$$

We want to prove:

If $S_n=Y_1+...+Y_n$ then $E[S_n] \sim log(n)$

Comment: This result does not have much to do with probability, and can be found easily by googling _Harmonic series_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linearity of expectation to get $$\sum_{m=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y_m]=\mathbb{E}[S_n]$$
One intuitive way to see why $$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac 1m \sim \ln n $$
Is to compute approximate the area under $$\frac {1}{x}$$ through the use of Riemann Sums and connecting that with the fact that $$\int \frac 1x \mathrm{d}x=\ln x$$

Comment: Yes, but my question is how I can prove that
$\sum_{m=1}^n\mathbb{E}[Y_m]=\sum_{m=1}^n 1/m \sim log(n)$

Comment: @Ana I added some details